# how should we remove dependency jar conditionally from maven

Tags: maven-2, weblogic11g

we have project that run on two different server. Tomcat and Weblogic.

but there are few dependency jars which are conflicting in weblogic because weblogic built in library have those jars.

So we have to delete those jars manually.

We are planning to delete do through pom.

One solution is we can make two separate for pom (one for tomcat and one for weblogic).
which is actually not sounds good.

We are thinking some how we can do profile based dependency exclusion. but any able to find any like for the same.

Please let me know if someone has some better suggestion.

We already tried to exclude jar from weblogic lib but unable to do it successfully.

All suggestions are openly invited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven profiles for building slightly different versions of your project for different application servers.

You can read about maven profiles 
[Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't work if the version provided by the container was out of date and it was not allowable to delete the dependency from the container's hosted libs / provide a new version via the POM.